Extract all text from url using Scrapy
I am working on a project to scrape web pages using Scrapy in Python. I want to extract all visible and not text from a web page. In addition to all text, I would also like to extract email addresses from mailto.
I'm sure there is a way to use Scrapy to extract all the text, but now I'm extracting by tags. What I mean is, I have an array of tags ['a', 'p', 'h1', ... 'span'] and I extract text from them by iterating over these tags, but this is not what I need because this text is added to the end of the line. I want all the text from the page to be organized.
Please help me with this.
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "webScraper"

    def parse(self, response):
        extracted_items = []

        for tag in ['a', 'p', 'h1', 'span']:
            element_texts = page_content.css(f"{tag}::text").getall()
            
            if element_texts:
                for element_text in element_texts:
                    processed_text = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", element_text).strip()
                    
                    if processed_text:
                        self.text_counter[processed_text] += 1
                        extracted_items.append(processed_text)
    
        return extracted_items

It works, but not the way I want it to.
For example this site:
For some reason, I didn't get anything out of it. I would like to get names, addresses, phone numbers, etc.
What I need:

A way to extract all visible text from the web page as it appears on the rendered page, maintaining the flow of the content.

A method to extract email addresses from mailto links on the page.

Extract phone/first name/last name




just one example: the mailto is in an a tag, but a isn't in your tag list. it appears you're lacking basic knowledge which makes your question too broad to be answered here

You have listed 3 independend questions explicitly and asked some more implicitly. You should focus on one problem and ask specific questions with code and expected results.

Boys it's example
I have 10 tags and a separate function to extract emails, but you didn't understand the question
you need to extract the entire page gradually tag by tag as it goes in the hierarchy

Please consider my question
Then give me your comments :)

Please consider my question we already told you it's not one question but many. three another hints: use you browser tools to inspect the page. each "card" is in a div of class rs-result. so instead of for tag in ['a', 'p', 'h1', 'span']: you could have for card in page_content.css("div.rs-result").getall():. if you can't get anywhere with this, it's because you need a proper tutorial about web-scraping. and that's not what stackoverflow is about

Okay, Please provide me with such textbooks or sources from which I can learn this.
